# Combox marcar/desmacar checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

tenho esse código que um botão marca e desmarca uma checkbox 
http://jsfiddle.net/H544C/1/

mais em vez do botão no meu caso seria um combobox que marca/desmarca checkbox

alguém poderia me ajudar? sou leiga no js..

fiz esse código porém ele marca a opção e não desmarca quando faço a troca no combobox

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-sm-2" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('perfil')} ? has-error">
                        <label for="perfil" class="control-label">Perfil</label> <select class="form-control" th:field="*{perfil}">
                            <option data-atendimento="ATENDIMENTO" value="ATENDIMENTO">Atendimento</option>
                            <option data-diretor="DIRETOR" value="DIRETOR">Diretor</option>
                            <option data-estoque="ESTOQUE" value="ESTOQUE">Estoque</option>
                            <option data-gerente="GERENTE" value="GERENTE">Gerente</option>
                            <option data-ti="TI" value="TI">T.I</option>
                            <option data-vendedor="VENDEDOR" value="VENDEDOR">Vendedor</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
  select.addEventListener('change', function() {
   var selecionada = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
   var atendimento = selecionada.getAttribute('data-atendimento');
   if (atendimento) {
    $('#permissoes3').each(function() {
     if (this.checked)
      $(this).attr("checked", false);
     else
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });

    $('#permissoes4').each(function() {
     if (this.checked)
      $(this).attr("checked", false);
     else
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });

    $('#permissoes6').each(function() {
     if (this.checked)
      $(this).attr("checked", false);
     else
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });


var select = document.querySelector('select');
  select.addEventListener('change', function() {
   var selecionada = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
   var diretor = selecionada.getAttribute('data-diretor');
   if (diretor) {
    $('#permissoes1').each(function() {
     if (this.checked)
      $(this).attr("checked", false);
     else
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });

    $('#permissoes3').each(function() {
     if (this.checked)
      $(this).attr("checked", false);
     else
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });

    $('#permissoes6').each(function() {
     if (this.checked)
      $(this).attr("checked", false);
     else
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
```

Comment: Você quer que ao marcar uma opção no campo `select` e clicar no botão, a opção marcada nao fique mais selecionada? Poderia explicar melhor o que precisas? Não ficou claro.

Comment: tenho um select com 5 perfils ao selecionar o select gostaria que marcasse o checkbox relacionado aquele perfil e quando mudasse perfil saisse o que estava marcado e selecionasse só a permissão daquele perfil

Comment: os perfils são permissoes ex: perfil atendimento só pode ver duas coisas, perfil diretoria pode ver tudo .. hoje é manualmente clico um por um para dar a permissão mais agora com perfil facilitaria pois automaticamente ele iria marcar o que cada perfil tem acesso

Comment: seria igual esse exemplo exatamente assim http://jsfiddle.net/H544C/1/ só que inves de usar botão seria select

Comment: onde está click (botão) seria o combo de select com os perfis e a idéia é a mesma de marcar/desmarcar

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro. Poste os campos que serão marcados automaticamente para eu criar um exemplo.

Comment: Jorge, os campos vem do banco de dados posso colocar uma imagem pois facilitaria você...

Comment: É necessário saber como os dados vem. Eles vem com alguma classe relacionado aos options do select?

Comment: cada dado vem com um id tenho 24 permissoes então permissaoA vem id=permissoesa , permissaoB vem id=permissoesb

Comment: Certo, agora o proximo passo: Como saberei quais permissões cada perfil do select tem?

Comment: só fazer o select marcar/desmarcar vai me ajudar demais pois vou "chumbar" os ids conforme as permissoes diretor tem todas então vai receber as 24 o atendente só tem 5 então vai ser só a,b,c,d,e

Comment: Ok, irei criar uma resposta.

Comment: obrigada Jorge.

Answer (score 1):

Criei um exemplo funcional para isso.

Algumas considerações são necessárias:

1- No seu campo `select`, adicionei uma opção sem valor para conseguir identificar o evento de `change`, se não tivesse colocado, o primeiro elemento selecionado não acionaria o evento a não ser que fosse trocada a opção.

2- Criei um objeto chamado `p`, nesse objeto você colocara todas as suas permissões seguindo o padrão descrito.

3- No final do `script` criei uma função chamada `setPermission`, a mesma receberá um array como parâmetro que conterá todas as suas permissões que você irá definir nos `cases` do `switch`.

4- No  `switch` será definido todas as permissões que o usuário terá. Essas opções foram definidas no objeto `p` no item 2. Vale lembrar que essas opções devem ser passadas dentro de um `array` para a função conseguir correr todos os itens selecionados.

Abaixo contém o exemplo:

```js
//objeto com todas as opções de permissão
let p = {
    'a': 'permissaoA',
    'b': 'permissaoB',
    'c': 'permissaoC',
    'd': 'permissaoD',
    'e': 'permissaoE',
    'f': 'permissaoF',
    'g': 'permissaoG',
}
$('#perfil').on('change',function(){
   let perfil = ('option:selected', this).value;      
   switch(perfil) {
       case 'ATENDIMENTO': 
           setPermission([p.a, p.b]);
           break;
       case 'DIRETOR':
           setPermission([p.a, p.b, p.c, p.d, p.e, p.f, p.g]);
           break; 
       case 'ESTOQUE':
           setPermission([p.a, p.b, p.c, p.d]);
           break;  
       case 'GERENTE':
           setPermission([p.a, p.b, p.c, p.d, p.e, p.f]);
           break;   
       case 'TI':
           setPermission([p.a]);
           break;  
       case 'VENDEDOR':
           setPermission([p.b]);
           break;   
           
       default: 
           alert('Indique uma opção');
   }  
   
});


/*Função responsável por setar as permissões. Receberá um array com todos os itens que devem ser marcados*/
function setPermission(permissoes = []) {
    //zera os checkboxs marcados
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false); 
    
    //loop para adicionar as permissões indicadas no array
    for(let i = 0; i < permissoes.length; i++) {
        $('#'+permissoes[i]).prop('checked', true);       
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-sm-2" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('perfil')} ? has-error">
                        <label for="perfil" class="control-label">Perfil</label> <select id="perfil" class="form-control" th:field="*{perfil}">
                        <option selected>Selecione uma opção* </option>
                            <option data-atendimento="ATENDIMENTO" value="ATENDIMENTO">Atendimento</option>
                            <option data-diretor="DIRETOR" value="DIRETOR">Diretor</option>
                            <option data-estoque="ESTOQUE" value="ESTOQUE">Estoque</option>
                            <option data-gerente="GERENTE" value="GERENTE">Gerente</option>
                            <option data-ti="TI" value="TI">T.I</option>
                            <option data-vendedor="VENDEDOR" value="VENDEDOR">Vendedor</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>  <br>

<input type='checkbox' id="permissaoA" class='marcar' name='check[]' />
<input type='checkbox' id="permissaoB" class='marcar' name='check[]' />
<input type='checkbox' id="permissaoC" class='marcar' name='check[]' />
<input type='checkbox' id="permissaoD" class='marcar' name='check[]' />
<input type='checkbox' id="permissaoE" class='marcar' name='check[]' />
<input type='checkbox' id="permissaoF" class='marcar' name='check[]' />
<input type='checkbox' id="permissaoG" class='marcar' name='check[]' />
                    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```